# Does GeoDjango 1.0.2 support django.contrib.messages?

Tags: python, geodjango

I am wondering if GeoDjango 1.0.2 supports django.contrib.messages because when I execute 'python manage.py syncdb', I am receiving the below error messages.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "C:\Program Files\GeoDjango\Django-1.0.2-final\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 340, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Program Files\GeoDjango\Django-1.0.2-final\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 295, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files\GeoDjango\Django-1.0.2-final\django\core\management\base.py", line 192, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Program Files\GeoDjango\Django-1.0.2-final\django\core\management\base.py", line 210, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "C:\Program Files\GeoDjango\Django-1.0.2-final\django\utils\translation\__init__.py", line 73, in activate
    return real_activate(language)
  File "C:\Program Files\GeoDjango\Django-1.0.2-final\django\utils\translation\__init__.py", line 43, in delayed_loader
    return g['real_%s' % caller](*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\GeoDjango\Django-1.0.2-final\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 209, in activate
    _active[currentThread()] = translation(language)
  File "C:\Program Files\GeoDjango\Django-1.0.2-final\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 198, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "C:\Program Files\GeoDjango\Django-1.0.2-final\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 181, in _fetch
    app = getattr(__import__(appname[:p], {}, {}, [appname[p+1:]]), appname[p+1:])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'messages'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The messaging framework was added in Django 1.2, so the answer to your question is probably 'no.' (See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/.)